# using multiple states with app.single

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I just want to know if I can use multiple states with app.single. My app shows blank when adding another state using app.single, but if I remove it the app shows again.

```
app.js
.state('app.checkin', {
      url: "/checkin",
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: "templates/checkin.html",
          controller: 'CheckinCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: "/checklist",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/checklist.html",
        controller: 'ChecklistCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.single', {
    url: "/checkekstra",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/checkekstra.html",
        controller: 'CheckekstraCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

let me know if my question is vague, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ui-router a state name is like an identifier. You can't name two routes with the same state name.

I'm pretty sure that if you check your browser javascript console you'll see an error. (And that's why it show you a blank page).

Comment: I see the error says: Error: State 'app.single'' is already defined.. thanks I appreciate it. @Okazari